# How to disable default TextInputPanel for an application?

Tags: wpf, tablet-pc

I have a wpf application (I use CAL) for a tablet pc. 
I created a custom text input panel.

Now is my question: How can I disable the default TextInputPanel?

This is only through my application offcourse because I still want the utility in my winxp and other apps on the tablet.

The problem is that when I hover to long near a textbox, the small tooltip to open a TextInputPanel always appears and I want to suppress that!

Kind regards,
Wim

Already posted at WPF Forums but with no result :s
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tabletandtouch/thread/835b910d-e357-4bd8-b26a-f99e7d549b3f
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c5bd3b90-c731-4e5b-a812-ee29490800e3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the Input Panel UI

Setting the DisableInPlace registry key to zero prevents the Input Panel user interface (UI) from appearing in an application. You must place the DisableInPlace registry key at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip. Then, add a new registry value by using the full path of the application in which you want to disable Input Panel. The following example registry entry disables Input Panel in an application called MyApp:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTIP\DisableInPlace]
"C:\Progam Files\My App\MyApp.exe"="1"
```

(Finally) Found this info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812266.aspx

I don't like it that much (reg. editing) but at least it's a solution ;)

Kind regards,

Wim